# How to read a log from a SVN path with spaces with SharpSVN?

Tags: uri, space, sharpsvn

I have a path in a repo with spaces like this:

```
https://mysvnserver.local/svn/branches/2.7 Feature XYZ
```

Now I want to read the log from this path using SharpSvn.

I have this code:

```
var client = new SvnClient();
client.Authentication.DefaultCredentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);

var logArguments = new SvnLogArgs(new SvnRevisionRange(startRevision, endRevision)) { RetrieveMergedRevisions = true };

var uri = new Uri(repoUrl);
Console.WriteLine("Absolute Uri: " + uri.AbsoluteUri);

Collection<SvnLogEventArgs> list;
client.GetLog(uri, logArguments, out list);
```

Absolute Uri displays:

```
https://mysvnserver.local/svn/branches/2.7%20Feature%20XYZ
```

which (for my understanding) is completely correct escaped for usage in the URI, but I then get an

```
SvnFileSystemException - File not found: revision 1612, path ´/branches/2.7_Feature_XYZ´
```

when the `client.GetLog()` is called. Telling from the error message, SharpSvn is replacing the spaces with underscores internally.

How can I prevent this and read the log messages from this path?

Edit Update:
Until now I tried to replace the space with `\`, `%20` and `+`. With no effects. The path can't be found. I also tried to pass the URI both with and without the trailing slash for all replacments above - also no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `"%20"` with `"\  "`

Comment: That's not possible. The `Uri` class automatically uses `%20` for spaces.